Journal forces me to provide figures in .pdf format, what can I do?
Approximately one year ago, I submitted my manuscript to a Wiley Journal. The submission was in full adherence with the submission guidelines. Upon submission, the journal requested color figures in TIFF format with at least 600 dpi. Back then, I generated these figures using Stata. In the meantime, the journal was transferred to Hindawi. My paper was now accepted and the journal does no longer accept my figures. They requested color figures in PDF. I have no longer access to Stata though. I tried to convert the existing figures using various converters / software, but I always experience a loss of quality / resolution. I guess this happens because I asked Stata to generate them in a very specific format/dimension. I explained the situation to the journal and they stated that they could not proceed without PDF Figures. They would not proceed with my accepted manuscript. To clarify, my figures are mainly contour plots, for which I do net understand why a PDF conversion is required. Could you provide insights in how to handle this situation?

@Daniel Hatton I have them in TIFF. Sorry, I did not mention it. I updated the question.

Do you want to meet the implicit expectations of the journal as well? They may expect vector graphics without saying so, and indeed translating from pixel graphics to vector graphics is not so easy. However, translating TIFF to PNG, and including the PNG in a LaTeX document, followed by running pdflatex will give you a lossless path to a PDF containing the original image in a pixel-perfect way.

@DCTLib Thank you for suggesting a path! I will try that. Do you think this would work for contour plots, as well?

@Dr.M If the Figure was nice and readable in TIFF form, it will be nice and readable as a pixel figure embedded in a PDF. Note that however some PDF readers will use non-pixel-perfect rescaling for showing the image, which may affect how it looks. Experiment with using "\includegraphics[interpolate=true]{}" and "\includegraphics[interpolate=false]{}" - in this way, you can ask the PDF reader (nicely) to interpolate or not interpolate your image when displaying the PDF.

Re: "I guess this happens because I asked Stata to generate them in a very specific format/dimension." Surely you can extract the aspect ratio and resolution from the TIFF file and then use that for an informed conversion with, e.g., tiff2pdf?

You might be able to use Stata at a university library. Of course, that depends on what universities are close to you and their policies. For example, “visitors may be issued guest credentials that allow them to use Library computers” at the University of Chicago (see https://www.lib.uchicago.edu/thelibrary/computers-and-wireless/ ). I would imagine many other universities have similar policies.

Hopefully, you will find a solution to their satisfaction by merely repackaging the tiff inside a pdf container file.
If you absolutely need to not only provide in pdf format, but at a resolution that is incompatible with your current raster file, you can try rescaling it to a different resolution. In my experience with cartographic images (admittedly not quite the same thing) Image resize... in paint.net (Windows) followed by some sharpening (with trial and error...) provides much better results than merely rendering a raster at a "wrong" resolution in a pdf viewer. It is free. If you are willing to consider paid solutions, Topaz Photo AI or Gigapixel will upscale images with AI; they are primarily for use with photographs but with some tinkering do a decent job with lineart and text labels in simple fonts.
Finally, you could vectorize the raster images with some effort. The old way of doing this used a drawing package like Inkscape to redraw curves and was timeconsuming. Now there is software like https://vectormagic.com/ and https://www.vectorizer.io/ which offer free trials to see if helpful, and then will cost about U$10 for an access pass.
All of this is suboptimal versus recreating the image at source, or just packaging the raster tiff as pdf to keep the publisher happy (which should be fine if the resolution is high). But I'm trying to outline the options if you are stuck complying.
